# Dividing rows within a multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, multi-index

Good evening all who happen to find this post!

I'm having a slight issue when it comes to dividing a stocks netIncome by its totalRevenue within a multiindex.

The code is as follows:

```
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si
import pandas as pd

company = ['AMZN', 'FB']

inc = {}
for ticker in company:
    inc[ticker] = si.get_income_statement(ticker)
df = pd.concat(inc)

pM = df.loc[(slice(None), ['netIncome', 'totalRevenue']), :]
pM
```

Now, all of this code should return me the company ticker, along with the net incomes and total revenue of the previous 4 years. Which is exactly what I need, and is all good so far...

I then want to take each company (ticker) in the index and divide the netIncome by totalRevenue (of the same company) and times that by 100 to get me a profit margin percentage...

If I use the code below it returns a load of NaNs within the rows...

```
test = pM.loc[(slice(None), 'netIncome'), :] / pM.loc[(slice(None), 'totalRevenue'), :] * 100
test
```

But if I manually type in the companies ticker like so:

```
pM.loc[('AMZN', 'netIncome'), :] / pM.loc[('AMZN', 'totalRevenue'), :] * 100

    endDate
2019-12-31    4.13087
2018-12-31    4.32527
2017-12-31    1.70522
2016-12-31    1.74355
dtype: object
```

It returns what I'm looking for, with that company...but obviously if I'm chopping and changing or have multiple stock tickers within the 'company' list then you can see it would be a bit long winded...

- Do I need to create a new row within the multiindex?
- Am I using the slice function in the wrong way?
- should I be using df.div?

These are all questions I've asked myself and cant find an answer, so my final solution is here on this forum!

Didn't really want to bother anyone with my questions, but I don't know what else to do :(

Thank you in advance, and hopefully everything I've written is clear, any issues let me know.

Comment: I think the first case is a DataFrame/DataFrame, in which case it fully aligns on both axes (requiring identical Series **and** column labels). The second case would be a Series/Series so there is only needs to align on the row-index. In the DataFrame/DataFrame case the issue is that your numerator has the label 'netIncome' while the denominator has the label ''totalRevenue' so nothing aligns. When you select the Series, like in your second case, these become the Series name, but Series division doesn't care about the name for alignment, just the row index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it failed was because the indices of the two operands were not aligned:

```py
>>> pM.loc[(slice(None), 'netIncome'), :]
endDate          2019-12-31   2018-12-31   2017-12-31   2016-12-31
     Breakdown                                                    
AMZN netIncome  11588000000  10073000000   3033000000   2371000000
FB   netIncome  18485000000  22112000000  15934000000  10217000000

>>> pM.loc[(slice(None), 'totalRevenue'), :]
endDate              2019-12-31    2018-12-31    2017-12-31    2016-12-31
     Breakdown                                                           
AMZN totalRevenue  280522000000  232887000000  177866000000  135987000000
FB   totalRevenue   70697000000   55838000000   40653000000   27638000000
```

pandas was looking for the label `(AMZN, netIncome)` in the second frame and there isn't one so the result of the revision is N/A. Same with the other rows.

---

What you wanted was `xs`:

```py
margin = (
    pM.xs((slice(None), 'netIncome'))
        .div(pM.xs((slice(None), 'totalRevenue')))
        .mul(100)
        .assign(Breakdown='profitMargin')
        .set_index('Breakdown', append=True)
)

pM = pM.append(margin).sort_index()
```

---

You can see how much work it takes just to add a metric to the data frame. That was because your `pM` frame was inefficiently designed. Try this instead:

```py
company = ['AMZN', 'FB']

inc = {}
for ticker in company:
    inc[ticker] = si.get_income_statement(ticker).T # ← added a `.T` here
df = pd.concat(inc)

df['profitMargin'] = df['netIncome'] / df['totalRevenue'] * 100
```

Comment: That's awesome! Don't think I would've ever got that! Thank you so much :D

Comment: I also see what you mean about my pM frame, I over complicated it when there was no need to! :)